# OPA5 test fails with "When.onTheWorklistPage.theTableShouldHaveAllEntries is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, testing, sapui5, qunit

I'm currently working on OPA5 tests for an SAPUI5 application and have encountered an issue with one of my test cases. The specific error I'm facing is: When.onTheWorklistPage.theTableShouldHaveAllEntries is not a function.
**Context:**

- I have a series of OPA5 tests structured within the **`ObjectJourney`** module.
- The test in question aims to verify whether pressing the 'Add' button on the worklist page displays the 'New Product' view.

**Problem:**

- The error occurs at a step in my test scenario when calling the **`theTableShouldHaveAllEntries`** function within the **`When.onTheWorklistPage`** object.
- It seems that this function is not recognized or properly defined within my test setup.

**What I've Tried:**

1. **Function Definition:** Checked the definition of **`theTableShouldHaveAllEntries`** within my page object (**`Worklist.js`**) to ensure it's correctly implemented and exported.
2. **Usage Verification:** Reviewed the usage of **`When.onTheWorklistPage.theTableShouldHaveAllEntries`** in my test scenario to match the actual function definition.
3. **Debugging:** Added console logs to trace the flow of execution and check the structure of **`When.onTheWorklistPage`** object.
   Code :
   webapp/test/integration/pages/Worklist.js:

   ```
   sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/test/Opa5",
    "sap/ui/test/actions/Press",
    "sap/ui/test/actions/EnterText",
    "sap/ui/test/matchers/AggregationFilled",
    "sap/ui/test/matchers/AggregationEmpty",
    "sap/ui/test/matchers/Ancestor",
    "./Common",
    "./shareOptions"
   ], function (Opa5, Press, EnterText, AggregationFilled, AggregationEmpty, Ancestor, Common, shareOptions) {
    "use strict";

    var sViewName = "Worklist",
        sTableId = "table",
        sAddButtonID = "addButton",
        sSearchFieldId = "searchField",
        sSomethingThatCannotBeFound = "*#-Q@@||";

    function createWaitForItemAtPosition (oOptions) {
        return {
            id: sTableId,
            matchers: function (oTable) {
                return oTable.getItems()[oOptions.position];
            },
            actions: oOptions.actions,
            success: oOptions.success,
            errorMessage: "Table with ID " + sTableId + " does not contain an item at position '" + oOptions.position + "'"
        };
    }

    Opa5.createPageObjects({

        onTheWorklistPage: {
            baseClass: Common,
            viewName: sViewName,

            actions: Object.assign({
                iPressTableItemAtPosition: function (iPosition) {
                    return this.waitFor(createWaitForItemAtPosition({
                        position: iPosition,
                        actions: new Press()
                    }));
                },
                iPressAdd : function () { 
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id:sAddButtonID,
                        viewName : sViewName,
                        actions : new Press(),
                        errorMessage : "Add button not found"
                    });

                },
                iRememberTableItemAtPosition: function (iPosition) {
                    return this.waitFor(createWaitForItemAtPosition({
                        position: iPosition,
                        success: function (oTableItem) {
                            var oBindingContext = oTableItem.getBindingContext();

                            // Don't remember objects just strings since IE will not allow accessing objects of destroyed frames
                            this.getContext().currentItem = {
                                bindingPath: oBindingContext.getPath(),
                                id: oBindingContext.getProperty("ProductID"),
                                name: oBindingContext.getProperty("ProductID")
                            };
                        }
                    }));
                },

                iPressOnMoreData: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        actions: new Press(),
                        errorMessage: "The table with ID " + sTableId + " does not have a button to show more items"
                    });
                },

                iSearchForTheFirstObject: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        success: function (oTable) {
                            return this.waitFor({
                                controlType: "sap.m.ObjectIdentifier",
                                matchers: new Ancestor(oTable),
                                success: function (aIdentifiers) {
                                    var sFirstObjectTitle = aIdentifiers[0].getTitle();
                                    return this.iSearchForValue(sFirstObjectTitle);
                                },
                                errorMessage: "Did not find entries for table with ID " + sTableId
                            });
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not find table with ID " + sTableId
                    });
                },

                iSearchForValue: function (sSearchString) {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sSearchFieldId,
                        actions: [
                            new EnterText({
                                text: sSearchString
                            }),
                            new Press()
                        ],
                        errorMessage: "Did not find the search field with ID " + sSearchFieldId
                    });
                },

                iClearTheSearch: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sSearchFieldId,
                        actions: new Press({
                            idSuffix: "reset"
                        }),
                        errorMessage: "Did not find the search field with ID " + sSearchFieldId
                    });
                },

                iSearchForSomethingWithNoResults: function () {
                    return this.iSearchForValue(sSomethingThatCannotBeFound);
                }

            }, shareOptions.createActions(sViewName)),

            assertions: Object.assign({

                iShouldSeeTheTable: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        success: function (oTable) {
                            Opa5.assert.ok(oTable, "Found the object Table");
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not find table with ID " + sTableId
                    });
                },

                theTableShowsOnlyObjectsWithTheSearchStringInTheirTitle: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sSearchFieldId,
                        success: function (oSearchField) {
                            var sSearchFieldValue = oSearchField.getValue();
                            return this.waitFor({
                                id: sTableId,
                                success: function (oTable) {
                                    return this.waitFor({
                                        controlType: "sap.m.ObjectIdentifier",
                                        matchers: new Ancestor(oTable),
                                        success: function (aIdentifiers) {
                                            Opa5.assert.ok(aIdentifiers.every(function (oIdentifier) {
                                                return oIdentifier.getTitle().indexOf(sSearchFieldValue) > -1;
                                            }), "All table entries match the search term");
                                        },
                                        errorMessage: "Did not find entries for table with ID " + sTableId
                                    });
                                },
                                errorMessage: "Did not find table with ID " + sTableId
                            });
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not find search field with ID " + sSearchFieldId
                    });
                },

                theTableHasEntries : function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        matchers: new AggregationFilled({
                            name: "items"
                        }),
                        success: function () {
                            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "The table with ID " + sTableId + " has entries");
                        },
                        errorMessage: "The table with ID " + sTableId + " had no entries"
                    });
                },

                theTableShouldHaveAllEntries: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        success: function (oTable) {
                            return this.waitFor({
                                controlType: "sap.m.ColumnListItem",
                                matchers: new Ancestor(oTable),
                                success: function (aItems) {
                                    var aAllEntities = this.getEntitySet("ProductSet");
                                    var iExpectedNumberOfItems = Math.min(oTable.getGrowingThreshold(), aAllEntities.length);
                                    Opa5.assert.strictEqual(aItems.length, iExpectedNumberOfItems, "The growing Table has " + iExpectedNumberOfItems +
                                        " items");
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not find table with ID " + sTableId
                    });
                },

                theTitleShouldDisplayTheTotalAmountOfItems: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        success: function (oTable) {
                            var iItems = oTable.getBinding("items").getLength(); // all items, incuding the growing list
                            return this.waitFor({
                                id: "tableHeader",
                                matchers: new Ancestor(oTable),
                                success: function (oHeader) {
                                    var sExpectedText = oTable.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("worklistTableTitleCount", [iItems]);
                                    Opa5.assert.strictEqual(oHeader.getText(), sExpectedText, "The table has a title containing the number " + iItems);
                                },
                                errorMessage: "The table header does not container the number of items " + iItems
                            });
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not find table with ID " + sTableId
                    });
                },

                theTableShouldContainOnlyFormattedUnitNumbers: function () {
                    return this.theUnitNumbersShouldHaveTwoDecimals("sap.m.ObjectNumber",
                        sViewName,
                        "Object numbers are properly formatted",
                        "Table has no entries which can be checked for their formatting");
                },

                iShouldSeeTheNoDataTextForNoSearchResults: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sTableId,
                        matchers: new AggregationEmpty({
                            name: "items"
                        }),
                        success: function (oTable) {
                            Opa5.assert.strictEqual(
                                oTable.getNoDataText(),
                                oTable.getModel("i18n").getProperty("worklistNoDataWithSearchText"),
                                "The table with ID " + sTableId + " should show the no data text for search");
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not find table with ID " + sTableId
                    });
                }
            }, shareOptions.createAssertions(sViewName))

        }

    });

   });
   ```

   Pages/NewProduct.js

   ```
   sap.ui.require([
    "sap/ui/test/Opa5",
    "./Common"
   ], function (Opa5, Common) {
    "use strict";
    var sViewName = "Add",
        sPageId = "page";
    Opa5.createPageObjects({
        onTheNewProductPage: {
            baseClass: Common,
            assertions: {
                iShouldSeeThePage: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: sPageId,
                        viewName: sViewName,
                        success: function () {
                            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "The 'New Product' title is shown.");
                        },
                        errorMessage: "Did not display the 'New Product' page."
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
   });
   ```
4. AllJoureney.js :

   ```
   sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/test/Opa5",
    "./arrangements/Startup",
    "./WorklistJourney",
    "./NavigationJourney",
    "./NotFoundJourney",
    "./ObjectJourney",
    "./pages/NewProduct"
   ], function (Opa5, Startup) {
    "use strict";

    Opa5.extendConfig({

        arrangements: new Startup(),
        viewNamespace: "opensap.manageproducts.ManageProducts.view.",
        autoWait: true
    });

   });
   ```

   ObjectJourney.js :

   ```
   /*global QUnit*/

   sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/test/opaQunit",
    "./pages/Worklist",
    "./pages/Browser",
    "./pages/Object",
    "./pages/App"
   ], function (opaTest) {
    "use strict";

    QUnit.module("Object");

    opaTest("Should remember the first item", function (Given, When, Then) {
        // Arrangements
        Given.iStartMyApp();

        //Actions
        When.onTheWorklistPage.iRememberTableItemAtPosition(1);

        // Assertions
        Then.onTheWorklistPage.theTitleShouldDisplayTheTotalAmountOfItems();

        // Cleanup
        Then.iTeardownMyApp();
    });

    opaTest("Should start the app with remembered item", function (Given, When, Then) {
        // Arrangements
        Given.iRestartTheAppWithTheRememberedItem({
            delay: 1000
        });

        // Assertions
        Then.onTheObjectPage.iShouldSeeTheRememberedObject().and.theObjectViewShouldContainOnlyFormattedUnitNumbers();

        // Cleanup
        Then.iTeardownMyApp();
    });

    opaTest("Should see the 'New Product' view after pressing the 'Add' button ", function (Given, When, Then) {
        // Arrangements
        Given.iStartMyApp();
        //Actions
        When.onTheWorklistPage.iWaitUntilTheTableIsLoaded().and.iPressAdd();
        //Assertions
        Then.onTheNewProductPage.iShouldSeeThePage().and.iTeardownMyAppFrame();
    });

   });
   ```

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCLiI.png)